# FALLBACK cache manifest doesn't work

Tags: html, fallback

I'm a asp.net developer and I'm using the HTML5 offline features but the FALLBACK isn't working as I expected: when the server is down, instead the page listed of opening the page in FALLBACK is presented the browser standard page of no connection.

In the manifest file I tried:
FALLBACK:
* /Default.htm

and I tried:
FALLBACK:
/ /Default.htm

and the "default.html" page is never opened when the server is down.

I tried in Google Chrome and in Firefox and result is the same.

What I'm doing wrong? Someone can help me?

Regards,
Carlos Pinheiro

Comment: Can you post enough code to reproduce the issue?

Comment: I have the same problem. I want a way to test it locally. Just getting off WAMPSERVER isn't enough.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Followed every resource online and the only detail that made my manifest work was removing the prefixed '/' before the fallback url.

In your example, change /Default.htm to Default.htm.

FALLBACK:
/ Default.htm